# Is there a version of Google Chrome Frame for Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there anything like Google Chrome Frame for Firefox?
(That would allow you to use the Chrome rendering engine within FireFox?)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I've seen is the cascading sequence of using [ETab to host Google Chrome Frame in IE Explorer.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ir2yA10OGs)